# Div stretching outside window in iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, viewport

Ok,

So I have a Div which is set to 100% width via Css (width: 100%;). In web browsers it displays fine. On iPhones (both in Safari and Chrome) it hangs over the screens but quite a few pixels (couple hundred). When setting at 100% width Android phones seem to fit the div into the screen.

I basically just want my div to fit in whatever container its in, but i think for some reason the iFrame is stretching it on iOS.

I tried setting a fixed width to test (e.g. width: 10px;), which is reflected in the web browser, but in iOS it is always the same width... I tried playing around with the @media in CSS, but the width will not change.

I also tried adding the following meta tag:

and added a fixed with css and applied to the div... still did not change the width..

I tried removing the div, just having an iframe of 10px, which is reflected on my laptop, but in ios it is still extremely wide...

I will try provide some screenshots to show what I mean, you can also feel free to visit the page I am talking about, however, you may need to join up to test: http://www.ozesports.net.au/chat

Ive posted an album for the below images as I can only post 2 links at the moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/raH7t.jpg

Page on laptop (Google Chrome)
1st img

Page on iOS (Safari)
2nd img

Page on iOS with me pinch zooming out so you can see its hanging over (Safari)
3rd img

Page on Android
4th img

I am really stuck, let me know if you need me to clarify anything..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try working with media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I Added:

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
         #ozechat {     
border-style: solid;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
}

The div seems to be the right size, fits on the ios screen, but the iframe is still super long, it just allows you to horizontally scroll now... :/ so my css selector is working for iphones, i just need to work out how to force the width of my iframe

Comment: I worked out that I had some inline styling that was setting the iframe to 4800 pixels wide, hence why this was occurring.

Playing with the inline styling helps adjust the iframe size